# how to display two json array values in single table cell in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, json, tablecell

I am new in objective-c and working on ios app where i am parsing json array and displaying it in table cell. I have the problem that i want to display 2 json array values in single cell but i am not getting the values properly, here is my json array

```
    {
    "event_id" = 7;
    "fighter_id" = 26;
    "fighters_name" = "Kaushik Sen";
    "fighters_photo" = "Kaushik.jpg";
    "match_id" = 28;
    "match_type" = Bantamweight;
    "profile_link" = "link";
  }


    {
    "event_id" = 7;
    "fighter_id" = 21;
    "fighters_name" = "Kultar Singh Gill";
    "fighters_photo" = "Kultar.jpg";
    "match_id" = 27;
    "match_type" = "Welterweights Main Event";
    "profile_link" = "link";
}
```

here i want to show the fighter name from two diffrent arrays in sigle cell, eg. kaushik sen vs kultar singh gill, but i am getting alternate player names in cells. here is my objective c code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self MatchList];
}



    -(void)MatchList {


    NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/appleapp/eventDetails.php"]];

    NSError *error;

    //code to execute php code
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:&error];


    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

    NSMutableArray *matchListArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    matchListArray = [json objectForKey:@"products"];
    arrayOfFighterName=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    arrOfMatchId = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for( int i = 0; i<[matchListArray count]; i++){

       // NSLog(@"%@", [matchListArray objectAtIndex:i]);
        arrayOfFighterName[i]=[[matchListArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"fighters_name"];
    }

}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [arrayOfFighterName count]/2;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell = (MyFighterCell *)[tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellIdentifier];
    select = indexPath.row;
    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[[MyFighterCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:kCellIdentifier] autorelease];
                [cellOwner loadMyNibFile:kCellIdentifier];
        cell = (MyFighterCell *)cellOwner.cell;

    }
    cell.lblPlayer1.text =  [arrayOfFighterName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.lblPlayer2.text =  [arrayOfFighterName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row +1];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is when you are writing the names to the cell. 
For each row, you are getting the current row, and the current row + 1.

So imagine you have fighters

```
0. John
1. Bob
2. Bill
3. Carl
4. Tom
5. Mark
```

Since the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: asks you to configure *every* row, what you are displaying is this:

```
Row 0: display 0 and 1 (John vs Bob)
Row 1: display 1 and 2 (Bob vs Bill)
Row 2: display 2 and 3 (Bill vs Carl)
```

What you need to do is change the way you get your fighters out.
Instead of displaying the fighters at the (current row) and (current row + 1), you need to be displaying 2*(current row) and (2*currentRow + 1)

```
Row 0: 0 and 1 (John vs Bob)
Row 1: 2 and 3 (Bill vs Carl)
Row 2: 4 and 5 (Tom vs Mark)
```

So, to fix your code by adding 4 characters:

```
cell.lblPlayer1.text =  [arrayOfFighterName objectAtIndex:2*indexPath.row];
cell.lblPlayer2.text =  [arrayOfFighterName objectAtIndex:2*indexPath.row +1];
```